# How do I backup system to a different partition on the same drive?

Tags: backup, lvm, ext4

I am a linux newbie, tech oldie.

I am setting up a system with Lubuntu 14.04. Although, when I ran the installation I created two partitions -- 1/2 for quickie backups and 1/2 for the installed system -- lubuntu ignored that and took my entire disk.

Yesterday, I spent a lot of time with the Redo Rescue disk manually recreating what I wanted.

Now, I have the following paritions:

```
/dev/sda1 ext2 /boot +- 200MB
/dev/sda2 extended +- 244GB
/dev/sda3 ext2 +- 220GB
```

sda1 and sda2 were created by the installer. I manually created sda3 after resizing those.

within sda2 is a logical volume

```
sda5 lvm2 pv lubuntu-vg
```

within sda 5
there are a swap partion and the root partition and nothing else. these were also created by the installer, but I resized them yesterday.

I want to backup sda1 and sda2 to sda3. I have been at this long enough to know that gives me zero protection from a disk failure. I just want to quickly be able to restore my work up to a certain point if I screw something up as I am tweaking the new system.

I have the qt4-fsarchiver LiveCD, the SystemRescueCD LiveCD and the Redo Rescue LiveCD.  As a linux newbie, I have been unable to figure out how to do this on any of these.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: Any time you deal with partitions, you should be very careful, since data might get destroyed.**

Try **dd**.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your  keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror,sync
```

To clone a partition

OR

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror,sync
```

To clone an entire hard disk

For more info see dd [Man Page 1](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) & [Man Page 2](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)

Comment: Thank you, Mitch.  I will give this a try.  I am curious, why notrunc and sync?  If I understand those correctly, they will expand the backup with empty space.

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526198/why-using-conv-notrunc-when-cloning-a-disk-with-dd.  sync,noerror is essentil to prevent dd from halting on an error, so it won't make a dump at the same location for each blocks, than source. conv=sync is no good without noerror.